# Setup issue with Magento module - adding attributes to categories

Tags: php, magento, module

This afternoon I've been trying to create a module in Magento that simply adds some more attributes to categories.

I'll run through the script I've created so far...

app/etc/Modules/Comp_Categoryattributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Comp_Categoryattributes>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Comp_Categoryattributes>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Comp/Categoryattributes/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Comp_Categoryattributes>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Comp_Categoryattributes>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <categoryattributes>
                <class>Comp_Categoryattributes_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>categoryattributes_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </categoryattributes>
            <categoryattributes_mysql4>
                <class>Comp_Categoryattributes_Model_mysql4</class>
            </categoryattributes_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <categoryattributes_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Comp_Categoryattributes</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </categoryattributes_setup>
            <ncategoryattributes_setup_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </categoryattributes_setup_write>
            <categoryattributes_setup_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </categoryattributes_setup_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And then finally, this one courtesy of http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/
app/code/local/Comp/Categoryattributes/sql/categoryattributes_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'twitter_user',  array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'Twitter Username',
    'input'    => 'text',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'twitter_user',
    '11'                    //last Magento's attribute position in General tab is 10
);

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'twitter_user');

$installer->run("
INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int')}`
(`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
    SELECT '{$entityTypeId}', '{$attributeId}', `entity_id`, '1'
        FROM `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity')}`;
");

//this will set data of your custom attribute for root category
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(1)
    ->setImportedCatId(0)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();

//this will set data of your custom attribute for default category
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(2)
    ->setImportedCatId(0)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

The module appears in the Disable Module Output area of the back end fine, but I don't see categoryattribute_setup appearing in the core_resource table at all? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Cheers guys,

Tom

Comment: Throw a die() at the top of your install script, flush cache, and hit any page of your site (just need Mage::run() to fire). See if you die.

Comment: ... and don't forget to remove the entry in the core_setup table for your module, otherwise no new installation will executed

Comment: Cheers for the replies chaps.

Ben - I've added a die() into my install script but the sites works as normal. I guess this pretty much confirms my thoughts that its not actually being loaded in. 

Danny - I don't see a `core_setup` table? It doesn't appear in `core_resources` though, where the rest of the _setup entries are for the other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skimming over it, I noticed that your config/xml file has the following:

```
<ncategoryattributes_setup_write>
```

Try removing the 'n'.

Comment: Yup, spotted, its always the little things that trip you over isn't it!